# Why doesn't my un-spayed female cat spray or rub herself on us or other stuff?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

I have a strange cat. She's very obedient to the point makes me think she's a dog. She's a year old. She isn't spayed but she never sprays. And she never rubs herself on objects.She never rubs on people either except when she's in heat. But only when someone is ready to give her food she may stick her tail up in a happy mood and maybe (sometimes only though) rub her head to back on the person welling to feed her and she does that just a little.

And comparing to what I've seen of cats on the internet and from personal experience my whole life, I've always seen cats rub alot on objects and people including me. She's been an orphan as a kitten but I don't think that prevents her from being a cat. She's been raised by us from the day she opened her eyes, and she's been living in our house ever sense.

When someone comes to give her love she'll lick their hands (well I wouldn't lie it's not someone, it's only ME and she rarely does that to another person, she usually just leaves when someone else tries to give her some love) but she wouldn't rub herself on the person whatsoever (whoever he/she is).

I'm sure she loves us because she's always following me around and she's always near whoever gets sick. And she's always happy when we come back from a long trip and tries to play with us.

So my question is WHY DOESN'T MY CAT EVER SPRAY OR RUN AGAINST THINGS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most definitive answer I can come up with is that your cat is FEMALE and not MALE and also the fact that she is INDOOR cat.

Quoting from the site [urine marking by female cats](http://www.usask.ca/wcvm/herdmed/applied-ethology/behaviourproblems/urinemark.html) only 5% of indoor female cats spray.

In case of rubbing oneself against furniture, the purpose is similar to spraying.

As given in the site [why do cats rub against legs and furniture](http://www.peteducation.com/article.cfm?c=21&aid=1132)

> Cats have scent glands on multiple places on their body including their faces and feet. On their face, the glands are located around the eyes, below the ears, and on the chin. By rubbing their face on various objects, such as legs and furniture, they are leaving their scent.

As the cat doesn't have the tendency to spray, (which is is done to mark territory and attract male cats) it also doesn't rub herself against furniture.

In my personal opinion, the fact which is also responsible for her behaviour is that she is an orphan cat and you have raised her since her eyes have opened. This has affected her psychologically. It is the mother cat who teaches her babies every single thing, and especially after opening of eyes it is the mother who is the only guide in this strange world.